# WSO2 : Unable to Engage New Module to Axis2 on Application Server

Tags: module, wso2

**The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available**

i wrote a module according to this sample [Writing a Apache Axis2 Module](http://insightforfuture.blogspot.com/2012/05/writing-apache-axis2-module.html). when i add TestModule.mar file using AppServer console, it is placed in this location

> \wso2as-.1.0\repository\deployment\server\axis2modules

but when i restart AppServer, it can not initiate and show this message

> The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available : TestModule

where i have wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of Appserver you are trying out?
You need to edit the axis2.xml, where you ahve to point your module and keep the module in the axis2modules directory. 
Check your module name you provided in the axis2 conf and original module name also same or different. If there is any spelling mistake it wont deploy the module.

Comment: Thanks dear Ratha. i use both Appserver 5.0.1 and 5.1.0 also i try to deploy this module to ESB 6.4.0 but i have same problem.i have placed my module file and axis2 config file in this address http://sdrv.ms/10zhhgr please check it if possible.thanks